# Turn someone's life around

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

> Turned someone's life around by mastering falconry.

1.**What does this mean?** (Is it his/her life has changed or he spent his whole time in falconry?)

2. **Can I use this in negative connotation?**

Comment: to turn one's life around: you are an alcoholic or drug addict or depressed etc. and doing something changes your life back to "normal". Like a car, it changes direction from bad to good. Anything a person likes can help to "turn his or her life around".

Comment: Ye! That's it! He a previous drug seller, then jailed(before he got out from prison), and eventually become a falcon master. Very nice and thx.

Comment: No worries. Drug dealer because a seller could be legit. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a book "H is for Hawk" by Helen Macdonald that describes how she took up falconry after a difficult time in her life. Having to concentrate on training the bird intensively freed her mind from her past troubles. That would be an example of someone turning their life round through mastering falconry. Maybe the phrase you quote is from a review of that book.